# How can I get the Material-UI DataGrid valueGetter to read data from a distinct object in an array?

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce, material-ui, mui-x

I am developing a React Admin Page for Woocommerce. I want to retrieve the 'option' value  from a specific object (product attribute with name = "Farbe") to display in a MUI DataGrid. I think that valueGetter would be the right approach, but can't get it to work.

Here's what I have:

The Woocommerce Product (row record):

```
    {
       "id": 232,
       "date_created": "2022-08-14T08:02:18",
       ...
       "attributes": [
          {
             "id": 0,
             "name": "Farbe",
             "option": "0045"
          },
          {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Material",
             "option": "Cotton"
          },
          ...
       ],
       ...
    }
```

The DataGrid column:
I am trying to select the object that has the value 'Farbe' on the key 'name'  and access the value of the property 'option'

```
export const VariationColumns  = [
    { field: 'id',   headerName: 'Id',   type: 'int', width: 100},
    { field: 'sku',  headerName: 'SKU',  type: 'string', width: 200},
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', type: 'string', width: 500, 
       valueGetter: ( params ) => { return params.row.attributes[name =>'Farbe'].option }},
]
```

But it can't find the 'option' property:
**"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'option')"**

Also tried:

```
valueGetter: ( params ) => { return params.row.attributes[name =>'Farbe'].option.value
valueGetter: ( params ) => { return params.row.attributes.name['Farbe'].option
valueGetter: ( params ) => { return params.row.attributes.name['Farbe'].option.value
```

Is there maybe a completely different approach needed to achieve this?
Any hint is greatly apreciated

Comment: Can you provide what the value of the `rows` prop that you would be passing to `DataGrid` in your example is? Is it just an array of what you provided as the row record? Need to know that to know how to access in the valueGetter. One thing to note is that valueGetter params as cell params, rather than row params.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `rows` prop looks like the record you provided above, you'd get it like so:

```
const rows = [
    {
      id: 232,
      date_created: "2022-08-14T08:02:18",
      attributes: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Farbe",
          option: "0045",
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Material",
          option: "Cotton",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

const variationColumns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "Id", type: "int", width: 100 },
    { field: "sku", headerName: "SKU", type: "string", width: 200 },
    {
      field: "attributes",
      headerName: "Name",
      type: "string",
      width: 500,
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.value.find((item) => item.name === "Farbe").option;
      },
    },
  ];
```

The key points are:

1. `valueGetter` params are cell params vs row params
2. The `field` property in the columns needs to match the field in your `rows`, so if you want to grab `attributes` you need to have `field: "attributes"` in your columns.
3. You can use `params.value.find((item) => item.name === "Farbe").option)` to return the object in the array that matches your desired search string, then access its `option` property.